# How can I store structure items in a variable

Tags: solidity, remix, struct, view

I am learning to code in solidity and stuck with view functions.
I am trying to return values taken dynamically in a structure using view function. Is there a way to do it is solidity? I tried it but it always throws an error "invalid opcode" or if I use loops it gives warnings like unreachable code.

Comment: Please provide your code example so that the community can help you.

Comment: Can you post the snippet that leads to invalid opcode?